# How to get an edge list (undirected graph) from a grouped dataframe in R?

Tags: r, nodes, edges, network-analysis

I have created a network where people are connected to specific events (participants to event 1 connected to node "event1").

I would like to know if it is possible to remove the node "event" and directly link together the people that took part in that event.

I have done something similar in the past using Excel to work on the raw data. I would like to know if there is a faster and better way to do it without leaving R.

The dataset looks like this:

```
net1
from        to 
Person 1   Event1 
Person 2   Event1 
Person 3   Event2
Person 4   Event2 
Person 5   Event2 
Person 6   Event3
...
```

As an example, I would like to delete "Event1" and connect Person1 and Person2 together as I am doing it.

I am sorry if I cannot provide a better code to work with. But I don't know where to start from to operate in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this using `tidyverse`.

1. `group_split` with the `keep = FALSE` argument splits the dataframe by the `to` column into a list of dataframes, while removing the grouping variable in the output.
2. `map_dfr` expands each dataframe by finding all combinations of `from` and itself (like `expand.grid`). `_dfr` means that the output list will be row-bind to form a dataframe.
3. `pmap_dfr` operates on each row of the dataframe, and sorts horizontally (`sort(c(...))`). `set_names` is needed to line up the columns after sorting. `tibble(!!!` splices the sorted vector into a row of the `tibble`, effectively turning it into a row vector.
4. `filter` and `distinct` removes self-loops and duplicate links respectively.

Note that both `group_split` and `group_map` are currently experimental functions. Please use with caution.

```
library(tidyverse)

net1 %>%
  group_by(to) %>%
  group_split(keep = FALSE) %>%
  map_dfr(expand, crossing(from, to = from)) %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ tibble(!!!sort(c(...)) %>% set_names(c("from", "to")))) %>%
  filter(from != to) %>%
  distinct()
```

or with `group_map`:

```
net1 %>%
  group_by(temp = to) %>%
  group_map(~ expand(.x, crossing(from, to = from))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-temp) %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ tibble(!!!sort(c(...)) %>% set_names(c("from", "to")))) %>%
  filter(from != to) %>%
  distinct()
```

or with `inner_join`:

```
net1 %>%
  inner_join(net1, by = "to") %>%
  select(from = from.x, to = from.y) %>%
  pmap_dfr(~ tibble(!!!sort(c(...)) %>% set_names(c("from", "to")))) %>%
  filter(from != to) %>%
  distinct()
```

We can also use `graph_from_data_frame` in place of `pmap_dfr` to return an undirected graph (be sure to load `igraph` *before* loading `tidyverse`, otherwise, you might get some unexpected errors):

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

net1 %>%
  inner_join(net1, by = "to") %>%
  select(from = from.x, to = from.y) %>%
  igraph::graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  igraph::as_data_frame(what = "edges") %>%
  filter(from != to) %>%
  distinct()
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  from     to      
  <chr>    <chr>   
1 Person_1 Person_2
2 Person_3 Person_4
3 Person_3 Person_5
4 Person_4 Person_5
```

**Data:**

```
net1 <- structure(list(from = c("Person_1", "Person_2", "Person_3", "Person_4", 
"Person_5", "Person_6"), to = c("Event1", "Event1", "Event2", 
"Event2", "Event2", "Event3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear (even for a noob like me) and detailed answer.  `inner_join` and `graph_from_data_frame` work perfectly fine.

Unfortunately, when running the other methods I get back: 
`Error in crossing(from, to = from) : unused argument (to = from)`
The question is perfectly answered so thank you again. However, solving this last issue may help others. Do you have any idea why I get back this error?

Comment: @ValerManf You will get this error if you load `igraph` _after_ `tidyverse` (I presume due to two different functions having the same name). If you wish to use both libraries, please be sure to load `igraph` first before loading `tidyverse` (restart your session and try again if you've already loaded `tidyverse` first).

Answer (score 0):

To create the edge list, we first split the data frame into a list of subgroups based on the group column. We then use the combn function to get all pair combinations within each subgroup. Finally, we create an edge list data frame from the matrix of pairs, with a from column representing the source node and a to column representing the destination node for each edge.

```
# Some sample data
df <- data.frame( 
  people=sample(paste0("Person", seq(5)), 20, TRUE),
  group=sample(paste0("Event", seq(3)), 20, TRUE)
)

# If the data frame contains duplicated rows, remove them
if(anyDuplicated(df)) df <- unique(df)

# Create a list of subgroups using the 'group' column in the data frame
group_list <- with(df, split(people, group))

# Use the 'combn' function to get all pair combinations within each subgroup
subgroup_pairs <- do.call(cbind, lapply(group_list, combn, m=2))

# Create an edge list data frame from the pairs matrix
edge_list <- data.frame(from=subgroup_pairs[1,], to=subgroup_pairs[2,])

head(edge_list)
```